# Why I can delete others' files on HDFS with only read permission

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, acl

I am not sure what is going on with our HDFS configuration, but I can delete other's files although the file permission looks fine and I only have read (r) access. What is possible problem here?

Comment: Check the permissions of the *containing* *directory* .

Comment: You will be able to delete a file if you have write permission for its directory

Answer (score 0):

See [Permissions Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_permissions_guide.html) in HDFS.

Check the permission in HDFS is enabled by checking the HDFS configuration parameter `dfs.permissions.enabled` in the **hdfs-site.xml** file which determines whether permission checking is enabled in HDFS or not:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is set to be "true". I guess there is something else going on.

Comment: Yes! I test it . Weird! Good question.